# Clear MongoDB cache in a sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, amazon-eks, bitnami, wiredtiger

I have a self-hosted MongoDB deployment on an AWS EKS cluster, version `1.24`.

Every time I put some workload on the cluster, the MongoDB shards eat most of RAM of the node. I'm running on `t3.medium` instances, and every shard uses ~2GB. Since there are multiple shards on each node, it just fills the memory, and the node becomes unavailable.

I've tried limiting the `WiredTiger` cache size to 0.25GB, but it doesn't seem to work.

I've also tried manually clearing the cache with `db.collection.getPlanCache().clear`, but it's doing nothing.

`db.collection.getPlanCache().list()` returns an empty array.

I've also tried checking the storage engine. But both`db.serverStatus().wiredTiger` and `db.serverStatus().storageEngine` are `undefined` in the mongoshell.

I'm using the bitnami `mongodb-sharded` [chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/mongodb-sharded), with the current values:

```yaml
mongodb-sharded:
  shards: 8
  shardsvr:
    persistence:
      resourcePolicy: "keep"
      enabled: true
      size: 100Gi
  configsvr:
    replicaCount: 2
  mongos:
    replicaCount: 2
    configCM: mongos-configmap
```

The mongos config map is this one

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongos-configmap
data:
  mongo.conf: |
    storage:
      wiredTiger:
        engineConfig:
          cacheSizeGB: 0.25
      inMemory:
        engineConfig:
          inMemorySizeGB: 0.25
```

Comment: Why do you have multiple shards on a single node? The main purpose of sharding is, to distribute the load over multiple machines, i.e. just the opposite. Parameter `storage.inMemory.engineConfig.inMemorySizeGB` is for [In-Memory Storage Engine](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/inmemory/), actually I am surprised that you don't get an error at startup when you set `storage.inMemory` and `storage.wiredTiger` parameters. Apart from that, `mongos` does not store any data at all, so `storage` parameters are ignored completely.

Comment: I'm surprised I don't get the error as well. That's why I think there is an issue loading the config file. Regarding the `mongos`, I've also tried putting the same config file on the `shardsrv` and `configsrv`, still not working.

Comment: Loaded configuration you can check with `db.serverCmdLineOpts()`

Comment: Ummm interesting: it's loading the `mongos.conf`, whereas if I shell in the shard, I see a second file called `mongo.conf` (without the `s`) that has my configuration. So I guess it's not loading the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Solved the various issues:

1. I had typo in the `ConfigMap` -> `mongo.conf` instead of `mongos.conf`. This meant that it was creating a different unused config file.
2. `mongos` are not the ones with the storage engine: that's on the `mongod` (the shards). So the config should be put in `shardsvr.dataNode.configCM`
3. Setting a custom config means that I'm overwriting the default one deployed by bitnami -> you would need to copy it all, and then modify what you need. A much better option would be to just add flags at `shardsvr.dataNode.mongodbExtraFlags`

In my case this is how I setup the `values.yaml`

```yaml
  shardsvr:
    dataNode:
      mongodbExtraFlags:
        - "--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB .3"
```

Another note: the reason `db.serverStatus().storageEngine` and `db.serverStatus().wiredTiger` were `undefined` was that I was running the `mongosh` from MongoDBCompass, which acutally connects to the `mongos` (which does not have a storage engine)

If instead you shell into one of the shards, and run `mongosh` (in my case it's at `/opt/bitnami/monogdb/bin/`) the commands work properly.